# Excel VBA: How to return a partial match

Tags: vba, excel, match

I've looked through the questions and can't seem to find an answer.

I have a list of receipt IDs in a spreadsheet, created by system 1. In another spreadsheet, I also have a list of the same receipts, created by system 2.

90+% of the information is presented the same, and I can run a Match using worksheetfunction.match. However, there is a particular type of receipt (a refund and purchase) that has a different format in system 2.

An example would be:

System 1:

- AAAA0000001
- AAAA0000002
- AAAA0000003
- AAAA0000004
- ....
- ZZZZ9999999

System 2:

- AAAA0000001
- AAAA0000002
- AAAA0000003 / AAAA000004      - this would be a refund and purchase
- AAAA0000005
- ....
- ZZZZ9999999

The code I am using is:

```
While MC > MD

    Worksheets("ID sheet").Activate                             ' activate ID sheet

    MF = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MD, Range("U2:W" & Range("U1")), 2, False)   ' Vlookup for System 1 letters
    MG = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MD, Range("U2:W" & Range("U1")), 3, False)   ' Vlookup for System 1 numbers
    MH = MF & MG                                                ' combine GFAS and Fund IDs

     Worksheets("System 1").Activate                ' Activate System 1 screen
        MI = WorksheetFunction.Match(MH, Range("HC:HC"), 0)         ' Match combined letters and numbers for System 1
        MK = Range("A" & MI)                                        ' Find deal ID

        Worksheets("System 2").Activate                         ' Activate System 2 screen
        ML = WorksheetFunction.Match(MK, Range("W:W"), 0)           ' Match deal ID in Range W
        MM = Range("F" & ML)                                        ' Find Register ID

        MD = MD + 1

    Wend
```

The code returns a run time error 1004.

Is there any way that I can get the code to accept the double entry as a match and return an answer?

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Related to the error: most likely is caused because the .Match function returns an error if it doesn't find anything, so you'll have to check for that: `If Not IsError(MI) Then`. Another way to get a partial match is to use the .Find() function

Comment: @paulbica - I've tried this method, but it seems to have an issue with the fact that the block of code is within a WHILE loop. I am now getting an error message saying that I have a WEND without an WHILE.

Comment: Please update the code you provided in the question to include the full context (where is the While line). It's easier to spot issues if you include the full function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood what you are matching to what, you can use:

```
MI = WorksheetFunction.Match("*" & MH & "*", Range("HC:HC"), 0)
```

Comment: This method works (a bit), but it is now returning the first row, which is a column header.

Comment: That should only happen if the header includes your search data.